# How to get current position in horizontal recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview and an imageview, I want to change imageview image on scroll but I don't know how to get the current position and by it get my image from the list then load it with Picasso to imageview!

here is my code:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_background"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
```

My Adapter :

```
public class Place_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Place_View_Holder> {
    private List<Place> objects;
    private Activity context;

    public Place_Adapter(List<Place> objects,Activity context){
        this.context=context;
        this.objects=objects;

    }

    @Override
    public Place_View_Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.place_item, parent, false);
        Place_View_Holder place_view_holder=new Place_View_Holder(v);
        return place_view_holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Place_View_Holder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(objects.get(position).getItem_Image())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.image)
                .error(R.mipmap.image)
                .into(holder.image);
        holder.place_name.setText(objects.get(position).getPName());
        holder.place_in_map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }
}
```

And this is my Activity

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    ////here i want to change imageview image
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: where is your activity code? and your adapter? put all of them here

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra I pull them

Comment: you want to do that without  clicks right? just scrolling the recyclerview at some position?

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra Yes just with scrolling I want to change.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
 SnapHelper mSnapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
 mSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
 LayoutManager recylerViewLayoutManager = new LayoutManager(view.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) ;;
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                   //Dragging 
                } else if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    review_position = recylerViewLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                 /*
                    Here load the Image to image view with picaso
                 */
                 Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(url)
                    .into(yourImageView, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            int firstVisibleItem = recylerViewLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
               /* Log.e ("VisibleItem", String.valueOf(firstVisibleItem));*/

        }
    });
```

Here

```
SnapHelper mSnapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
```

This makes the horizontal recycler view to show and scroll entire one item at time so you cannot get stuck in middle like half visible and another half invisible

Comment: This solution is so simple it's downright elegant. I've been using code that is infinitely more complex to do the same thing.

Comment: This solution is not accurate. SCROLL_STATE_IDLE state would call even if you are at the edge (last / first item) and every swipe would trigger this state.

Answer (score 2):

**Find the Position of Current Item from Recycleview**

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener ( new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {  

              @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                    if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                        //Dragging
                    } else if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                        int position = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                        Log.e("position", String.valueOf(position));

                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: While this code snippet might solve the issue and provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please consider an [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.