# How can I fix the position of buttons in a RecylerView layout? I don't want the buttons to scroll along with the image in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using a recyclerview and I want to stop scrolling of the complete layout on scrolling left or right.

If it is not possible, is there a way to get the itemposition without a click Interface so that I can put the buttons outside recylerview?
The buttons are placed in a cardview.

[image: Layout]

Comment: You can put the buttons outside the recyclerview and if you're using a SnapHelper a listener exists for the page change event (https://medium.com/over-engineering/detecting-snap-changes-with-androids-recyclerview-snaphelper-9e9f5e95c424)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the button layout below to recycler view in xml of activity from item layout.

Comment: The buttons perform function of sharing image. How can I get the position of item in recycler view if I don't include the button click interface in adapter class?

Comment: You can get the position by adding scroll listener on recycler view like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766324/how-to-get-current-position-in-horizontal-recyclerview?rq=1